# google-play-services library cannot be resolved after adding another library

Tags: android, android-library

My app project is using `google-play-services` library, and there is no problem with that. But if I add a new library (my own library), `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap` and other classes related to Google Maps are marked as **cannot be resolved**.

I thought it was because of name conflicts, so I made a new library with an empty class and no methods, but same issue happened.

All of them, the libraries and project are for Android 4.0. Any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the console for the error? I suspect the different versions of `appcompat v4` used by `google-play-services` and your libraries. Try copying one version to the other.

Comment: thanks for the editing, ok, you were almost there. The problem was that appcompat_v7 has its own android-support-v4.jar that is incompatible with my project's one. I've deleted one of them and it's ok now.